# Fourier transform and inverse Fourier transform of rectangle function between $x_1$ and $x_2$.

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I'm given the function:

$$\psi(x)=\begin{cases} A &: x_1<x<x_2\\ 0 &:\text{outside} \end{cases}$$

So, I'm using the Fourier transform and its inverse to show that I'll get the original function $\psi(x)$ back.
$$\phi(k)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\psi(x)e^{-ikx}dx=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{x_2}^{x_1}Ae^{-ikx}dx\Rightarrow \phi(k)=-\frac{A}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\frac{1}{ik}\left(e^{-ikx_2}-e^{-ikx_1}\right)$$

I'm struggling to apply the inverse Fourier transform to get back the original function:
$$\psi(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\phi(k)e^{ikx}dk=-\frac{A}{2\pi i}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k}\left(e^{ik(x-x_2)}-e^{ik(x-x_1)}\right)dk$$
I'm not sure how to integrate this.

Comment: You're right, I didn't notice. It is still difficult to integrate though; I have no idea of how to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following trick:

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{ik}\left(e^{ikb}-e^{ika}\right)dk
=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{a}^{b} e^{ikx} dx\, dk 
=\int_a^b\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{ikx} dk\, dx
=\int_a^b 2\pi\delta(x)\,dx=\begin{cases}2\pi, &\mathrm{if}\, 0\in(a,b)\\ 
0, &\mathrm{if}\, 0\notin(a,b) \end{cases}  $

Comment: But how to show it without the detour into $\delta$-function formalism?

Comment: Thank you! I wouldn't have noticed that trick.